# Send redirect to url in post method

Tags: javascript, servlets

I am trying to add parameter and redirect to a page that only accepts request in post method. I am using this code in my servlet and it is not forwarding me to the url.

```
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String url = "http://www.thisone.com";
    InputStream in = null;
             try {
                    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
                    PostMethod method = new PostMethod(url);

                    //Add any parameter if u want to send it with Post req.
                    method.addParameter("User", "xyz");
                    method.addParameter("Name", "abc");

                    int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
                    System.out.println(statusCode); 
                    if (statusCode != -1) {
                        response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL(url));
                        in = method.getResponseBodyAsStream();
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to redirect with post method using this approach. what you can do is get the response to the client and therefore set the location header in response. Implementation for the same is given below:

Once your condition is satisfied:

```
response.setStatus(307);
response.addHeader("Location", "<url>");
```

also check out the significance of 307 status code.

Here is the javascript code, which starts with an ajax request and hit a servlet to fetch the desired URL, once it receives the URL, creates a HTML form object, sets values and submits the form...

```
<script>
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            callURL(this.responseText);
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", "TestServlet", true);
    xhttp.send();

    function callURL(url){
        var form = document.createElement("form");
        form.setAttribute('method', 'POST');
        form.setAttribute('action', url);
        form.setAttribute('id', 'frmProduct');
        form.style.display = 'none';

        var i = document.createElement('input');
        i.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        i.setAttribute('name', 'name');
        i.setAttribute('value', 'Neeraj');
        form.appendChild(i);
        document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(form);
        form.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Below is the implementation of my Testservlet

```
@WebServlet("/TestServlet")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public TestServlet() {
        super();
    }
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String url = "http://www.thisone.com";
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print(url);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do I pass parameter using this

Comment: Let me clarify how sendRedirect works. Once you execute sendRedirect, the request goes back to the client and then URL in your browser gets changed and then it's redirected. 

So you're anyways redirecting from client side. What you can do is get the URL on client side. pass parameters using javascript and then post the request to the desired URL.

if you want me to write the implementation for the same, let me know....

Comment: Thanks for your help Neeraj but I need to send values by set parameter not by set Attribute

Comment: Let me clarify one more thing, what you're thinking is an attribute, is actually parameter. if its get method, this is how the request will look like, http://<url>?name=neeraj
if you want to add more parameters, just add another input tag
hope it helps....

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of automatic form submit using POST method to do the same.

Please find below sample code:

```
public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    sendPOSTRedirect(request, response);
}

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    sendPOSTRedirect(request, response);
}

private void sendPOSTRedirect(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    String postURL = "url to send data";
    String value1 = "value for name1";
    String value2 = "value for name2";
    String content = "<html><body onload='document.forms[0].submit()'><form action=\"" + postURL + "\" method=\"POST\">"
            + "<INPUT TYPE=\"hidden\" NAME=\"name1\" VALUE=\"" + value1 + "\"/>"
            + "<INPUT TYPE=\"hidden\" NAME=\"name2\" VALUE=\"" + value2 + "\"/>"
            + "</form></body></html>";

    response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.write(content);
}
```